# Error text increases TextFormField height which leads to overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So i have a few TextFormFields inside scrollable column and it works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uruG.gif), until error text [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zsf4.gif). Because it causes bottom overflow. The desired behavior is button that just jumps up and don’t cause overflow. I have tried to put textfield inside a container with fixed height but after error text appear it just shrinked textfield

```
Form _buildForm(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
print(constraints);
return Form(
  key: _form,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48, bottom: 32),
              child: Text(
                'Sign Up',
                style: AppTheme.theme.textTheme.headline3
                    .copyWith(color: AppColors.black),
              ),
            ),
            LabeledTextField(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              fieldName: 'Email',
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'example@mail.com'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_userNameFocusNode);
              },
              onSaved: (val) => _authData["login"] = val,
              validator: FormValidators.emailValidator,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            ),
            LabeledTextField(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              fieldName: 'User Name',
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'alexexample...'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
              },
              onSaved: (val) => _authData["username"] = val,
              validator: FormValidators.isRequiredValidator,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            ),
            LabeledTextField(
              fieldName: 'Password',
              focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type in...'),
              onSaved: (val) => _authData["password"] = val,
              validator: FormValidators.passwordValidator,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            ),
            Spacer(),
            AuthButtons(
              mode: AuthMode.signup,
              saveForm: _saveForm,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(64),
        title: 'title',
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => _buildForm(context, constraints),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

LabeledTextField is basically just a textFormField with Text widget before it

```
class _LabeledTextFieldState extends State<LabeledTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: widget.margin,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.fieldName,
            style: AppTheme.theme.textTheme.caption
                .copyWith(color: AppColors.darkGrey),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            initialValue: widget.initialValue,
            textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
            focusNode: widget.focusNode,
            onSaved: widget.onSaved,
            onChanged: widget.onChanged,
            validator: widget.validator,
            onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
            autovalidateMode: widget.autovalidateMode,
            obscureText: widget.obscureText,
            decoration: widget.decoration,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why did you comment  //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, ?

Comment: cos i need button to go up, when the keyboard is opened so thats why resizeToAvoidBottomInset should be true

Answer (score 1):

You can try expanded instead of a container as a parent widget or use wrap as a parent widget on your text field.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`

```
class _LabeledTextFieldState extends State<LabeledTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: widget.margin,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
       physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),  // u can ignore this if u want
        child : Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.fieldName,
            style: AppTheme.theme.textTheme.caption
                .copyWith(color: AppColors.darkGrey),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            initialValue: widget.initialValue,
            textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
            focusNode: widget.focusNode,
            onSaved: widget.onSaved,
            onChanged: widget.onChanged,
            validator: widget.validator,
            onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
            autovalidateMode: widget.autovalidateMode,
            obscureText: widget.obscureText,
            decoration: widget.decoration,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```